# What's the difference between using 'the' or 'these' in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, difference, definite-article, demonstrative

> These apples are red.
> The apples are red.

I think in the second sentence the meaning is that all apples are red, am I right?
Also, using 'the' in this example is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both are ways of designating some particular apples.

If you use *these*, it is **deictic**: designating them by (literally or metaphorically) pointing to them. Probably they are physically present and nearby; or else one of you has just mentioned them.

If you use *the*, it is not deictic: you are referring to some particular apples and expect your interlocutor to know which apples you are talking about: usually, they have already been mentioned in the conversation, but it might be that you were both expecting to have a conversation about some apples.

In some cases, either is possible.

Answer (score 0):

These apples are here (nearby). Those apples are there (further away). The apples might be here, there or anywhere - using "the" means that they are a particular group of apples, but doesn't say where they are. If you say the apples are red, all the apples in that group are red, but there are apples not in the group.